# Paypal Transactions using Rest

Tags: c#, rest, api, paypal

I want to get all the transactions in a paypal account using their REST API and C#.

Is this possible? I've looked through the API docs and I can't find anything which seems strange. Has it been deprecated?

Thankyou.

Comment: Please note, this site is not here to wirte code for you, or explain docs - I'm sure the PayPal docs will tell you all this information. Instead, go and write some code, try it out and come back here if you get stuck.

Comment: I am actually having the same question. I even read that with the REST API you can only query transactions made with the REST API. This is strange

Answer (score 0):

You can use TransactionSearch method. [TransactionSearch Documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/TransactionSearch_API_Operation_NVP/)

Note: The maximum number of transactions that can be returned from a TransactionSearch API call is 100.

Comment: This is the old API. They seem to have deprecated this. I'm wondering how you do this in their new, REST-based API. I've spent an hour on their developer site and can't find how you would do such a simple thing. I don't want  code or docs explaining, it's a pretty simple question and a reasonable thing to ask. Thankyou.